# Python script for web scraping or clicking a specific DOWNLOAD button

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to automate a python job for downloading a daily CSV file.
The method: Web Scraping the site [www.auroravision.net/](http://www.auroravision.net/)
Which is a site for solar energy production monitoring.
What I have so far is the following python code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
username = "*****"
password = "*****"
url1 = "https://www.auroravision.net/dash/report/home/app/index.jsf#/"
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/filepath/chromedriver")

driver.get(url1)

driver.implicitly_wait(10)

driver.find_element_by_name("userId").send_keys(username)
driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys(password)
driver.find_element_by_name("login-btn").click()
```

So far so good, I passed down my login details and can now proceed to click the DOWNLOAD button. At this point I have tried using tags, name, id...but cant seem to make it work.
Any suggestions?

[Screenshot of website where DOWNLOAD button appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAHxH.jpg)

I understand it is difficult to help me since the page cannot be accessed without login details so I'll post here the website code that appears when inspecting the DOWNLOAD button:

```
<button class="btn btn-success btn-sm ng-binding" ng-show="report.uiStatus == 'READY'" ng-click="downloadReport(report.id)">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></span>
            Download
          </button>
```

Comment: One more thing: your full name appears in that screenshot. Remove it. (And make a habit of only using your real details where absolutely necessary).

Answer (score 0):

You are using deprecated syntax: `find_element_by_*` was replaced with `find_element(By.*, ..)`. Next - you are not waiting for elements to load. Use something along the lines:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
[...]
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
[...]
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[@ng-click="downloadReport(report.id)"]'))).click()
```

Providing there isn't another button with the same attribute/attribute value **before** that button, this should click that button.

EDIT: If that button is in some iframe and shadow root, you will need to switch to that iframe/ get into that shadow root prior to locating the element.

Selenium documentation can be found here: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/